# REST Node.js and express Evented I/O for V8 javascript has stopped working

Tags: node.js, express, intersystems-cache

I tried creating a new database object in each call and I still get the same error. (because of  variable scope shouldn’t they be different objects in each call?)

Here is the function called.

```
    exports.get_type = function(req, res ) {

  var query=""; // in case we want to filter
  if(req.query.term)
  {
    query=(req.query.term).toUpperCase();
  }
  var typeString=(req.params.type).toUpperCase();

  var globals = require('C:/Program Files/nodejs/cache082');
  var objdb = new globals.Cache();
  objdb.open(
  {
    path:"D:/Program Files/Cache/mgr",
    username: ruser,
    password: rpwd,
    namespace: rnsp    
  },
  function(error, result){
   if (!error) {
        console.log('DB Open : Getting Dictionary Type list:'+typeString);

        objdb.function({function:"getDic^UTIL", arguments: 
[typeString,query]},function(error,dic){
          var response = dic.result;

        //send response
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
          res.send(response);
        });

   }
   else 
   {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
     res.send(500, { error: "Database Error" });
   }

  });  // ends     
};
```

Comment: What's the error? You write "stopped working" does it mean it was working before you did something?

Comment: Hi SSH, the error is Evented I/O for V8 JavaScript has stopped working.  it works fine with one call, but when having multiple calls close together. I get the error.

Comment: This is Cache, right? Not Globals DB? Do you have license installed? With no license you can only have one connection at a time